# R running code with ctrl+alt+R

Tags: r, utf-8, shortcut

I want to run a script through ctrl+alt+R.

Yet, I only can through ctrl+AltGr for with ctrl+alt+R it only works partly. This is the chunk getting me mad:

```
part <- "Geniuses"

spread_title <- "Literature"
if (rulang) spread_title <- "ÐÐ°ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ"
if (author_to_report == "william") short_text <- "to be or not to be."
if (author to report == "lev"  & rulang) short_text <- "Ð¡Ð½Ð¸Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð."
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this Windows/RGui?

Comment: Yes, it is.I have added some special character getting the situation worse and encoed in UTF 8.

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes, RStudio, last version.